# Is it wrote or written

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

I saw a blog where it shows "written by" and not "wrote by" someone.
Anybody please explain why? 
Is writing wrote by wrong?

Comment: Have you done any research on the tenses of the verb? What example sentences of each verb tense did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> James Herbert wrote this book

This sentence uses active voice: the verb is in simple past tense.

> this book was written by James Herbert

This sentence uses [passive voice](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/passives). In passive voice, we use the past participle for the verb, regardless of when it happened- even in the future. In this sentence, **was** indicates that it happened in the past. **write** is an irregular verb, and the three main forms are

> write - base form 
>   wrote - past tense
>   written - past participle.

You can find more about irregular verbs [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/irregular-verbs).